# Can not install Launch Navigator plugin. Asking for google api key

Tags: ionic-framework, plugins

I am trying to install the launch-navigator plugin into ionic4 framework:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/launch-navigator

It is failing with exit code 1. In the stack I find the following:

```
Failed to install 'uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator': Error: Variable(s) missing: GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID
```

¿Can it be installed without the API key? ¿Why does it needs the API key?

What I want to achieve is to launch google maps (or other navigation app) with given coordinates so I can provide a way to navigate from the current GPS position to the given coordinates position.

¿Any suggestions or workarounds?

Comment: google provides API key for maps / geolocation usage. go to this link and generate your api key : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But I want to avoid using the API key since I will need to pay if the usage grows. If some one can provide a workaround would be perfect.

Comment: The API is free but it comes with limit. if you exceed the limit then you will be charged. otherwise you can use leaflet maps : https://leafletjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

use this command to install it smoothly.

```
ionic cordova plugin add uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator --variable GOOGLE_API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="{your_api_key_here}"
```

if you don't have Google API key then

follow google map API documentation...

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Answer (score 0):

I tried to open an address using the Launch navigator. Couldn't make it work. Took a more simpler approach and it worked like a charm, in  iphone, android phone and pwa.

```
openMap(){
  var baseUrl;
  // use angular platform to find if ios
  if (this.platform.is("ios")){
    baseUrl='http://maps.apple.com/?q=';
  }else{
    baseUrl='https://maps.google.com/?q=';
  }
  const q=this.address.line1+','+
  this.address.city+','+
  this.address.state+'-'+
  this.address.zip;
  window.open(baseUrl+q);
}
```